# How do I get numpy arrays (wav signals) out of a dataframe to process?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, wav

I compiled a dataframe with over 300K wav signals in the form of a numpy array and then exported them to a .csv for later use. The dataframe looks like this:

```
        signal_wav                                          label
323302  [-0.03637242, -0.04163716, -0.0382735, -0.0407...   tag1
323303  [0.0052252985, 0.0074647125, 0.0071932683, 0.0...   tag2
323304  [-0.05064101, -0.0662319, -0.109769195, -0.110...   tag3
323305  [-0.0332708, -0.029734522, -0.025742473, -0.02...   tag4
323306  [-0.0069274902, -0.008087158, -0.008178711, -0...   tag5
```

Then I created a function to extract features from each signal within the dataframe like this:

```
def get_mfcc(signals, sr):
    
    all_signal_mfccs = []
    for signal in signals:
        mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=signal, sr=sr)
        all_signal_mfccs.append(mfcc)
        
    feat_df = pd.DataFrame(all_signal_mfccs)
    
    return feat_df
```

However, when running the function I keep recieving the error "ParameterError: Audio data must be of type numpy.ndarray". I tried adding a portion of code that converts the original signal within the row from the dataframe using "np.asarry" or "np.array" but then I get the error saying that the data is a not in float format.

I understand it might have something to do with the dtypes, maybe? I also tried "pd.to_numeric" for the "signal_wav" column specifically but that didnt work either.

All I am trying to do is, iterate through the "signal_wav" column and read each array to process them and extract its features.

Comment: if the lists are coming in as strings, try using eval() -- sometimes that will be clean enough to turn the value to a real list and then you can manipulate it from there. If that doesn't work, post full dataset instead of truncated values or a good mockup of the data.

Comment: Just tried eval(), doesn't work either. Can't post the full dataset, its way to big. A few arrays alone take up all the characters left on here.

Comment: a link to a few lines of the csv file??? it's difficult to help without having the data as you are reading it.

Comment: How do you call `get_mfcc(...)`? At the first line of your function, insert `print(type(signals))`. What is the output?

Comment: i get this, <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: Do you try `mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=np.asarray(signal), sr=sr)`?